# Java replaceAll() regex does not work

Tags: java, regex, special-characters

I'm trying to replace all special characters with a "%", like:

```
"123.456/789" -> "123%465%798"
```

my regular expression is:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

In online tools* it works perfecly, but in java

```
s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "%");
```

strings remain untouched.

*I tried: http://www.regexplanet.com/  http://regex101.com/ and others

Comment: `s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "%");` Strings are immutable.

Comment: @ZouZou: omg thx! 4 secs, nice response time xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are immutable. You forgot to reassign new `String` to the `s` variable :)

```
s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "%");
 // ^ this creates a new String
```

Comment: I'm not your buddy, pal.

Comment: What `dude` are you all talking about ? :)

Answer (score 4):

`replaceAll()` like all methods in String class, DO NOT modify `String` on which you invoke a method. This is why we say that `String` is immutable object. If you want to 'modify' it, you need to do

```
s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "%");
```

In fact you don't modify `String s`. What happens here is that new `String` object is returned from a function. Then you assign its reference to `s`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change a String, instead replaceAll returns a new value. so you should use it like this

```
String newStr = s.replace(...)
```

Comment: It's fantastic how fast problems are being solved on stackoverflow

Comment: When they are this simple...

Answer (score -1):

Working code as per your expectations :)

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Regex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "123.456/789";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+");
        String newStr = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "%");
        System.out.println(s + " -> " + newStr);
    }
}
```

Output : **123.456/789 -> 123%456%789**