# convert newline to br textarea java servlet

Tags: java, regex, servlets

I'm trying to convert below message to represent in the text Area which i got from the The JAVA Rest API call ([Thirdpaty](https://8gwifi.org/crypto/rest/pgp/pgp/pgpencrypt))and the message  is this

```
String x =   "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----\nVersion: BCPG v1.58\n\nhIwDmCS94uDDx9kBA/4jkqEOWjbe03C1Dgd2A9eDBdk6cYczsOu6Typm0kjT15uQ\nT+Qc4Koz/yIq4gQpwccxRQ9NGl3Bi1cmPYvwxHIe+4bmqd31Izdkaj1VJCEVqZl2\nrLZvogFOo1oHUmdL2uIdUQJGJgslEOh91wp7CfxGhlxKSg0PvY3gyyWyofUwx9JU\nAUu+NY6YYrfd2l95C7EmMJXUDPysCitl/TGy04DbMuMNAyjZPPfkXqvjcG4A10nk\nPujs6RjnRYyCk+3ZJxvkhsjvGXKIQi7gTgWz7AV8vkBhSM2M\n\u003dRtkb\n-----END PGP MESSAGE-----\n"
```

When the message displays in the HTML text Area after applying regex patterns

```
x.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", "<br />");
x.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", "<br />");

<textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="test" name="test"><%=pKey%> </textarea>
```

still appearing like this

[image]

**The Expected Output I'm not getting is this** 
[image]

Comment: Are you assigning the value to `x`? See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436517). Also, is the `\n` a literal string? Then you need `x=x.replace("\\n", "<br />")`. Or `x=x.replaceAll("\\R+", "<br />")`.

Comment: You should change your regex like this:

   `x.replaceAll("\\n)", "<br />");`

otherwise the `EOL` character `\n` will be taken into account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, `x=x.replace("\\n", "<br />");` it will work

```
PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();

    pw.println("<textarea name='suggest_list' rows='10' id='word_suggest'>");
    pw.println(x);
    pw.println("</textarea>");
    pw.println("</body></html>");
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: it will work in the System Console without replacing, it's not working on the Text Area

Comment: @anish I Just edited